# Gitlab pipeline access to docker repo?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

gitlab installed in linux machine and pipeline failed because it doesn't have access to docker reposatory
docker repo inside gitlab
with the below error

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Get 
https://docker.*****/v2/operator/kubectl/manifests/1.15: unauthorized: HTTP 
Basic: Access denied (executor_docker.go:188:0s)
```

---

I found the issue in bridge as the below
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether 02:42:dc:8d:c0:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

---

systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-07-21 11:54:45 UTC; 19min ago
Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Main PID: 4488 (dockerd)
Tasks: 37
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
└─4488 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Jul 21 11:54:44 agora dockerd[4488]: time="2020-07-21T11:54:44.168245639Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Jul 21 11:54:44 agora dockerd[4488]: time="2020-07-21T11:54:44.168261691Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Jul 21 11:54:44 agora dockerd[4488]: time="2020-07-21T11:54:44.168739695Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jul 21 11:54:44 agora dockerd[4488]: time="2020-07-21T11:54:44.660694452Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/
Jul 21 11:54:44 agora dockerd[4488]: time="2020-07-21T11:54:44.843200704Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jul 21 11:54:44 agora dockerd[4488]: time="2020-07-21T11:54:44.870880302Z" level=warning msg="failed to retrieve runc version: unknown output format: runc ver
Jul 21 11:54:45 agora dockerd[4488]: time="2020-07-21T11:54:45.887294851Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=2d0083d graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=18.09
Jul 21 11:54:45 agora dockerd[4488]: time="2020-07-21T11:54:45.887403804Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jul 21 11:54:45 agora dockerd[4488]: time="2020-07-21T11:54:45.928154658Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Jul 21 11:54:45 agora systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
lines 1-19/19 (END)...skipping...

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to docker registry

```
before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
```